# In Angular, why doesn't line breaks affect the HTML?

Tags: angular

In my Angular 6 application, I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<p [innerHTML]="description"></p>
```

The above is rendered like this:

[image]

Why doesn't the line breaks "show" in the browser?

**Note!** I'm using `[innerHtml]` because the `description` variable can sometimes contain html.

Also, I have tried string replacing line breaks with `<br>` tags, but had no effect.

Comment: I see you've looked into `<br>`, white space beyond a single space is never rendered unless inside a `<pre>` tag but those are rarely used these days.

Depending on the doctype you are complying with for your page you might need to make sure your `<br>` are typed as `<br/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Style property `white-space` like this -

```
<p style='white-space: pre-wrap' [innerHTML]='description'></p>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxcqye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Reff. - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7781#issuecomment-408117841